# Which containers to store objects for access via different identifiers?

Tags: c++, std

I have to access my objects (multiple instances from one class) via several different identifiers and don't know which is the best way to store the mapping from identifier to object. 
I act as a kind of "connector" between two worlds and each has its own identifiers I have to use / support.
If possible I'd like to prevent using pointers.

The first idea was to put the objects in a List/Vector and then create a map for each type of identifier. Soon I had to realize that the std-containers doesn't support storing references.

The next idea was to keep the objects inside the vector and just put the index in the map. The problem here is that I didn't find an index_of for vector and storing the index inside the object only works as long as nobody uses insert or erase.

The only identifer I have when creating the objects is a string and for performance I don't want to use this string as identifer for a map.

Is this a problem solved best with pointers or does anybody have an idea how to deal with it?

Thanks

Comment: What is the disadvantage of storing pointers instead of references? They aren't that different really.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to iterate through a vector/set/list/whatever of objects in several different orders? What exactly do you mean by 'identifier'?

Comment: @heinrichj Well for starters you can't store references, not in a standard container anyway.

Comment: This might be a case where pointers might be good. For this you might want to look at e.g. [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

Comment: you can also use `std::ref` but I find `shared_ptr` more suitable in this case.

Comment: @Azerius: I'm writing a Tapi Service Provider. "Identifier" is an integer-type used by the TapiServer on the one side and the cti software or pbx on the other side to tell me which of my objects they want to do something or for which of my objects they have information. This can be handles, pointers, indices etc. When connecting to the application I get the information that e.g. my 1st object now has identifier 0x05A6481F, my 2nd object has identifer 0x01AFD... and so on.

Comment: So why can't you have a `std::map` of IDs that map to object pointers? This is clearly a situation where pointers would be useful.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I realize that; I was merely implying that if you forget about the limitations of references that prevent their use in standard containers, they are not much different from pointers. I would also advise using std::shared_ptr if the dynamic allocation cost is acceptable (though using a custom deleter could allow storing the instances in a vector if random removes are unlikely).

Comment: Could you show the interface you want to provide? Btw: as long as you don't want to actually share ownership of the objects between your list and some other mechanism i'd rather use unique or weak_ptr

Comment: Thanks to all your answers! I wasn't aware of the C++11 types ref, shared_ptr and weak_ptr until now. I have to read the description, look whether MSVC2010 supports them and then decide whether I use std::ref, shared_ptr/weak_ptr or MyObject*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using pointers seems reasonable. Here's a suggested API that you could implement:

```
class WidgetDatabase {
 public:
  // Returns true if widget was inserted.
  // If there is a Widget in *this with the same name and/or id,
  // widget is not inserted.
  bool Insert(const std::string& name, int id, const Widget& widget);

  // Caller does NOT own returned pointer (do not delete it!).
  // null is returned if there is no such Widget.
  const Widget* GetByName(const string& name) const;
  const Widget* GetById(int id) const;

 private:
  std::set<Widget> widgets_;
  std::map<std::string, Widget*> widgets_by_name_;
  std::map<int, Widget*> widgets_by_id_;
};
```

I think this should be pretty straightforward to implement. You just need to make sure to maintain the following invariant:

> w is in widgets_ iff a pointer to it is in widgets_by_*

I think the main pitfall that you'll encounter is making sure is that name and id are not already in widgets_by_* when Insert is called.

It should be easy to make this thread safe; just throw in a `mutex` member variable, and some local `lock_guards`. Optionally, use `shared_lock_guard` in the `Get*` methods to avoid contention; this will be especially helpful if your use-case involves more reading than writing.

Comment: Sorry for replying so late, I was working on another project in the meantime. I had already solved it with maps to pointers (as I got convinced by the comments).  However, my capsulation is not as good as your approach. I think I will have to improve this on next refactoring...

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered an [in-memory](https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html) SQLite database? SQL gives you many ways of accessing the same data. For example, your schema might look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Widgets {
  -- Different ways of referring to the same thing.
  name STRING,
  id INTEGER,

  -- Non-identifying characteristics.
  mass_kg FLOAT,
  length_m FLOAT,
  cost_cents INTEGER,
  hue INTEGER;
}
```

Then you can query using different identifiers:

```
SELECT mass_kg from Widgets where name = $name
```

or

```
SELECT mass_kg from Widgets where id = $id
```

Of course, SQL allows you to do much more than this. This will allow you to easily extend your library's functionality in the future.

Another advantage is that SQL is declarative, which usually makes it more concise and readable.

In recent versions, SQLite supports concurrent access to the same database. The concurrency model has gotten stronger over time, so you'll have to make sure you understand the model that is offered by the version that you're using. The [latest version](https://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html) of the docs can be found on sqlite's website.